# Java :Not able to download spreadsheet using google drive API

Tags: java

I am trying to download a file from the drive using google drive api

Steps to reproduce :
Step 1:
Click on :https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export#try-it
Step 2:
I have provided fileid and mimetype
I gave fileid and mime type as "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet" and click on execute.i got this error:
"code":403,
      "message":"Export requires alt=media to download the exported content."

```
public static void downloadFile(Drive service,String fileId) throws IOException{
        OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        //OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("/Users/xxxxx/Downloads/driveFile.xls");
        //service.get 
        service.files().export(fileId,"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
        .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
    }
```

Comment: mmm, your question is not clear ☹

Comment: I have used https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileid}/export  to download a file .i gave input parameters file ID and mime type.i got response as bad request

Comment: and where is your code?

Comment: I have used this link https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export#try-it .From here i am getting 403 error code .                                                                      And here is my code , from the code also I am getting 403 error code .          How do I paste the code, as it is not accepting whole code here because of it exceeds the limit

Comment: @SuvarnaLakshmiGodavarthy, just edit your question to add your code.

Comment: Code has been added.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you are getting...

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads

Try adding "?alt=media" to your GET request. My guess is you are missing something in the input parameters or possibly do not have access to the media (not logged in maybe?). I can't help more without seeing the actual code you are attempting to call, or the request you are making.

Comment: How do i post the code here as it is exceeds the limit when i tried to post